# Sharepoint 2010 - Location of V4.master

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know the location of the V4.master for Sharepoint 2010?

Comment: I whole heartedly recommend Everything (http://www.voidtools.com/) to solve all your file finding needs (so long as you know at least *part* of the file name). It's bloody super-quick and there is a portable version too. My whole team can't live without it now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be in the master page gallery. Browse to /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Or if you open the site in SharePoint Designer 2010, you can browse to "master pages" on left side to see v4.master

On the server: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Comment: But do you know where on the server it is stored?

Comment: in this folder: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Comment: What about a custom master created using SPD?