# i need to deploy a sharepoint solution

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have updated a theme on Sharepoint 2010 site.
The site is a sandboxed development site.
The changes consist of updates to a master page, new css and some small images files as used on the home page.  There are also some web parts implemented on the home page.

Now these changes need to be deployed as part of a Sharepoint Solution to a production environment.

I don't have direct and full access to the server which is hosted by a third party.

So my question is, is it possible to create a SP Solution to be deployed and how can I create it?

(I didn't know before I started developing it, that I would be required to create the SP Solution)

Answer (score 0):

If the changes are just updates to the master page, css and image files, you can just overwrite the existing ones in the hive 14 folder (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14). Be sure to make a backup first.

You can also use SharePoint Designer on the machine that has Central Admin installed to make changes to CSS and the master page. It is very easy and intuitive to do so.

See here for more information [Sharepoint 2010 - Location of V4.master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127026/sharepoint-2010-location-of-v4-master) and good luck!